# How to output more than one API request in Flask?

Tags: python, json, flask

I have several API GET calls I need to do and see the output on a webpage. I'm new to Flask, and I'm only able to print the output of one request call.

I also would like to know how to format the output. I'm able to print a name, but I want the output to look like

I get this:

> John

I want this:

> Name: John

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def getInfo():
    url = 'some url'
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you gather your variables (your GET requests in your case) and then supply them to your template to render.

```
@app.route('/')
def getInfo():
    url = 'some url'
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    other_response = requests.get(url).json()
    return render_template('example.html', foo=response, bar=other_response)
```

Then in your `example.html` template you could access those variables:

```
<h1>Super Whizzy Webpage</h1>
Name: {{ foo.name }}
```

Handling templates and variables is all covered in the [Flask quickstart documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#rendering-templates).